# Class not found error if same class is not used in each file

Tags: php

**About**

I am using PHP 7.4. There is no framework used. There are 2 files. 1. Index.php 2. LoginController.php

Please notice that this line of code `use application\Loading\AppResource;` is needed in both files.

Is there any way to declare this class in index.php only? I meant, instead of declaring it in each file, can I do it one time only in index.php only?

**Index.php file**

```
include_once 'application/Config/AppConfig.php';
include_once 'application/Config/RouteNamesConfig.php';
include_once 'application/Loading/AppResource.php';


use application\Config\AppConfig;
use application\Loading\AppResource;
use application\Config\RouteNamesConfig;

$pageName = str_replace(AppConfig::requestUri, "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

if($pageName == RouteNamesConfig::LoginPage) {
    AppResource::Load("Controllers", "Auth.LoginController");
    LoginController::CreateView();
}
```

**LoginController class is present in another file**

```
use application\Loading\AppResource;

class LoginController {

    public static function CreateView() {
        AppResource::Load("Views", "Auth.Login.Main");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should that be possible? Each individual file has to declare the classes used

Comment: Also, why not use a proper autoloader? That would at least help to avoid the manual `include_once` calls

Comment: auto loader will load all the files immediately. There is no conditional loading. Am I moving in right direction?

Comment: If you don't want to `use` every class you need in every file you need it then don't use namespaces.

Comment: Ok, then @Pankaj you will need to do `include_once 'application/Loading/AppResource.php';` at the top of the LoginController. That's what you are missing because you aren't using an autoloader. The LoginController has no idea how to get to the file it's supposed to rely on.

Comment: @hppycoder: That has already been done in index.php file. Should I do it again in Login Controller?

Comment: "auto loader will load all the files immediately" - no, why should it do that?

Comment: did you try spl_autoload?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload

Answer (score 1):

The `use` statement does not "declare" a class, it [creates an "alias" for it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). This alias is  valid only **within the current file or namespace block**.

If this wasn't the case, it would defeat the point of namespacing, because as  soon as you wrote `use application\Config\Exception;` in any file, the class name `Exception` would refer to that class, rather than the built-in `Exception`, or some other class in a different namespace.

On the other hand, you do not have to write any `use` statements at all; all they do is give you a short-hand for referencing something within that file. Importantly, they do *not* trigger the autoloader, or require the referenced class to ever exist.

So the following files are completely equivalent:

```php
namespace application\Controllers;

class LoginController {

    public static function CreateView() {
        \application\Loading\AppResource::Load("Views", "Auth.Login.Main");
    }
}
```

and

```php
namespace application\Controllers;

use application\Loading\AppResource;

class LoginController {

    public static function CreateView() {
        AppResource::Load("Views", "Auth.Login.Main");
    }
}
```

and even

```php
namespace application\Controllers;

use application\Loading\AppResource as ALAR;

class LoginController {

    public static function CreateView() {
        ALAR::Load("Views", "Auth.Login.Main");
    }
}
```

Whichever of those you use, it is up to you to actually include the definition of the class whose full name is `application\Loading\AppResource`, once, somewhere in your application.

The usual way to do this is to [define an autoloader function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which determines which file to include the first time a class is referenced in the code.

Increasingly often, even this isn't written by hand, instead the project is configured to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which will generate an autoloader for both your own code and the libraries you use.

Comment: Should I remove all the namespaces and that way just include it once at the top level and use it in all the classes written below that scope? That way, it will avoid code redundancy. Imagine a case of change in folder structure which will lead to change in `use` line of code in all classes. Am I thinking in correct way?

Comment: @Pankaj If that was a good idea, PHP wouldn't have namespaces at all. Changing the folder structure should be considered the same as renaming a class - you do it when it's necessary to improve the application, not just because you're in the mood for it.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, I am not sure at all so looking for your valuable advise. `include/include_once` has done the class loading job. Loaded classed can be accessed now written below that scope (without using the `use` keyword). right? So, don't you think it is altogether unnecessary to have namespaces? Please don't mind, I am just a beginner.

Comment: @Pankaj Namespacing is not about how the class is loaded; it is about how it is **named**: it allows you to have a class called `application\Loading\Config` and a class called `application\UserManagement\Config` at the same time, and to arrange your classes into logical groups. The [PHP manual has an introduction to the concept](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Once you have an autoloader, and arrange your classes into files matching their names, you'll never think about `include` and `require`, you'll just write code assuming they exist.